Accelerate natvis for type-erased "any"-style class
Our large code base has a class AnyRef that contains a type-erased reference to some object:
struct AnyRef {
    int type = 0;
    void* ptr = nullptr;
};

For example, if type==1, then ptr is pointing to an instance of a class Foo1. To simplify debugging in Visual Studio (we don't use VSCode for that), we have a natvis file that looks like this:
<AutoVisualizer xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/debugger/natvis/2010">
  <Type Name="AnyRef">
    <Expand>
      <Item Name="Type" Condition="type==1">"Foo1"</Item>
      <Item Name="Object" Condition="type==1">*((Foo1*)ptr)</Item>
      <Item Name="Type" Condition="type==2">"Foo2"</Item>
      <Item Name="Object" Condition="type==2">*((Foo2*)ptr)</Item>
      ...
    </Expand>
  </Type>
</AutoVisualizer>

The classes that AnyRef can reference are generated via some external code generation tool, and there are hundreds of them. The tool also generates the natvis entries, and there are therefore hundreds of entries in the natvis <Expand> element. We also have a few other classes like AnyRef that use type erasure and for which hundreds of natvis elements get generated, too.
Problem: The result is that the Visual Studio debugger hangs for 1 minute as soon as a breakpoint is hit because it is busy loading the natvis content. Afterwards it is fast, but it is quite annoying since the hang happens everytime one fires up the debugger and stop the execution.
My current workaround is to remove the content from natvis that I am not interested in locally; e.g. I know that I personally am almost never interested in Foo1 but only Foo2. But we cannot really implement this globally, because members of another team usually look at Foo1 and never at Foo2.
Also, the workaround has the problem that our version control (SVN/git) of course shows the natvis file as modified, and care must be taken not to commit it.
Question: Does anyone have an idea how to write the natvis file in a way that allows the debugger to load it more efficiently? The <Expand> element is basically a long sequence of if(...){} if(...){} statements, which obviously is quite inefficient (since it needs to evaluate every single if-statement). I was thinking about somehow converting it to some map-style/lookup-table-style structure, but apparently natvis does not support something like this? Any other ideas?

Tell Microsoft to optimize their code. Even if there was a thousand ifs with a thousand characters each, this should take well under a second to parse and execute.

Yeah, well, chances are that this will take months or years before they do it, if ever  So I had hoped to find a short-term workaround.

Seems more like a variant of pointers than any.

If changing the .natvis file locally is an acceptable solution, and the only problem is that it must not be committed, then you can git update-index --skip-worktree <file> to force it to not be updated by git.

Regarding git skip-worktree/assume-unchanged: I tried working with that, and it was very annoying and confusing, especially when the natvis file gets updated by someone.

Just an idea, try to segment visualizers into multiple files based on commonly used modules instead of using a monolithic Natvis file,  enabling more efficient loading based on need.

@DouXu-MSFT thanks for the suggestion, but what do you mean with "based on need"? Do you mean that the developers can then more easily delete locally the files unimportant to them? (Which is somewhat annoying with respect to git...) Or do you mean that visual studio by itself might load only the files that are actually required? But also, how would I segment the visualizer for a single class such as AnyRef into multiple files?

I mean visual studio may load the .natvis files they are actually required. You created multiple .natvis files e.g: AnyRef1 and  AnyRef2. One scene only loads AnyRef1,another scene only loads AnyRef2. Not sure if it's possible. And sorry for ignoring it is a single class.
